# Charge user a variable amount

Tags: android, android-billing, android-inapp-purchase

I need to implement a feature in the app where  I charge users a variable cost for a certain product.  Basically the user can set a budget  (any number) and I need to charge the user that budget

I understand that in app products prices are set in the console ahead of time. How can I over come this problem so I charge the user a cost that he specifies through in app billing?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can charge for a lot of products at specific steps in a slider bar. For example, breaking up $100 into 10 parts ($10 each) or 20 parts ($5 each).  This isn't a truly variable system per-say, but it gets "close enough" for most applications.

Make sure to give them names that are not based on price but on steps and the version of the step, ie, v1_25. This way if you want to update or change your slider you can give it a new version with new prices, etc.

As a side note, if you plan to support iOS your plan will totally fail and most likely so will what I just suggested. You can only price based of pricing tiers there so you have far less control of prices you want to apply.

You may wish to consider a different approach.

Answer (score -1):

You can use paypal or stripe instead of In App Purchase.

Comment: I can't use them for digital purchases as per Terms of Service. It has to be google billing